# Scifi book about intelligent blob aliens and nanotech

Tags: story-identification, books

I read it years ago and just can't remember what it was called or who wrote it.

It's about blob aliens and nano tech. Humans are a spacefaring species and have met and live along side, on many planets, a blob species of alien. Only the females of the blob species are sentient though and they keep their wild unintelligent males on a preserve for mating purposes.

But there is one male that is intelligent but has to pretend he's female and teams up with a human cop (I think he was a cop) to stop nano tech terror attacks on the settled worlds.

Comment: I left the Larry Niven tag, but are you certain about that?  It doesn't seem familiar to me.

Comment: I agree with @DavidW, and I think it would make more sense to have that information in the body of the question - maybe even if they're sure.  More visible that way.

Comment: I've read everything Niven wrote, and pretty sure it's not him.

Comment: Y'all are right, definitely not Larry Niven. I left that tag cause I wasn't sure what the tags were about so just put my favorite author.

Comment: I hope this gets identified cos I wanna read it